# How to get value of jquery nice select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing an script that using [nice select](https://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/) :

```html
<div class="nice-select form-control "   tabindex="0"><span class="current">تعداد حمام</span>
    <ul class="list" >
        <li data-value="1" class="option selected focus">1 حمام</li>
        <li data-value="2" class="option">2 حمام</li>
        <li data-value="3" class="option">3 حمام</li>
        <li data-value="4" class="option">4 حمام</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I check the documention and it have just two method:

```js
$('select').niceSelect('update');

$('select').niceSelect('destroy');
```

It didn't say how to get the selected value , i google it too but anyway i couldn't get the selected value and another point is that i have more than one `nice select` in one page

How can i handle it?

Edited: 
Thanks @jorge-fuentes-gonzález  and this is the [snippet/fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unlocker/u02whjvr/5/)  , can you help to get the selected value?

Comment: why you are not using `<select>` tags?

Comment: @Zeljka Because they are using _nice select_...

Comment: @Martin check nice select documentation.. he should use `select` tags

Comment: Maybe try `$('select').val()` I recall most jQuery plugins to return values this way.

Comment: @Zeljka I presume they are using that and the output is what has been pasted into the question

Comment: @Keff he doesnt have select element in html thats the problem

Comment: Yup, just realized that! Good observation

Comment: you should add your select option here, nice select create `ul` `li` from `select` `option`

Comment: thanks for attention guys , the `$('select').val()` return just undefined   , what do you suggest that should i do?

Comment: Add a working snippet/fiddle please, to save us time.

Comment: @meti Sorry, but I would use select2 (`https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage`), not `nice select`, I know that its not problem solution but in general you dont have lot of options with this `nice select` plugin

Comment: @jorge-fuentes-gonzález i bring it to snippet/fiddle please take a look if you can , @Zeljka thanks for suggestion but the whole project used `nice-select` its would better if i can get the value , and change the nice scroll is my last solution.

Comment: Meti, as people already stated, you should use `select` instead of `ul`, `li` and such. If you read the documentation here: https://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/ you will see examples using `<select>` and not `<ul><li>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have incorrect HTML. [As you can see in the documentation](https://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/), you have to create a normal HTML `<select>`, like this:

```
<select id="myselect">
  <option data-display="Select">Nothing</option>
  <option value="1">Some option</option>
  <option value="2">Another option</option>
  <option value="3" disabled>A disabled option</option>
  <option value="4">Potato</option>
</select>
```

Then pass to it the niceSelect plugin:

```
$("#myselect").niceSelect();
```

And you will be able to get the value using simple JavaScript over your `<select>` tag:

```
var selected = $("#myselect").val();
```

niceSelect plugin is simply a wrapper. Creates HTML over your `<select>` HTML, but your `<select>` HTML still exists on the page, but hidden, and you can continue working with it:

[image]

BUT you need to use `<select>` tags, not `<ul><li>` tags. I don't know where you got your code, but documentation is your friend. I've updated your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/o7a4dtwv/